# Paint on an object using Three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, html5-canvas, textures

I want to paint on an objects surface using the mouse.

Here's an example of what I want to do:
http://www.cartelle.nl/deathpaint/

Does anyone know of any basic example of how to do this?

I guess you paint on a canvas and then that is applied on to the 3D object in some way.
Anyone knows how this is done?

Comment: Take a look into [THREE.DecalGeometry](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/geometries/DecalGeometry.js) ([example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_decals.html))

Comment: Thanks! Is that the same? It seems so much more slower? But I'll have a dig. https://www.clicktorelease.com/code/decal-splatter/

Comment: Hm, I think it is not the same, decals would be really slow there since drawing happens often. Probably drawing directly on mapped texture should be used. I think applicable solution could be rendering uv's to a texture -> looking up a uv area around mouse -> changing color of those uv's of original texture's copy -> swapping texture which is in use on model. But that approach will require a model to have uv's.

Comment: Ctrl + U will show you the source code of the page from your link.

Comment: @prisoner849 Hehe! I was waiting for it ;) I just wonder if this is some known tech and if there is a basic project of this. But I will probably dissect the death paint tomorrow.

Comment: first thing you have to care about is projecting 2d mouse coords to 3d world space and determining wether the click was on the model (three.js raytracer would help here)

Comment: Something similar : http://maximumroulette.com/framework/3d_Tshirts_desing/project_instance/tshirts.html?tshirts . This is simplest variant 2dcanvas->texture->webgl , Secund is based on raycast https://threejs.org/examples/?q=texture#webgl_materials_texture_tga . this example gives you uv position for edit (in background put canvas2d with same textures for edit -on mouseup reload new texture)

Comment: @nikola-lukic cool. I can't paint on the t-shirt though.

Comment: Theres one example in my memory ... But i cant found it on three.js example . Pull from git three.js project than revert to the older version and try to found example . It is just what you want .. paint direct on 3d object ....

Comment: @nikola-lukic yes I sort of have that feeling too that I have seen it. I'll try to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found this, **chameleon.js**

https://tomtung.github.io/chameleon.js/

Seems to do exactly what I wanted.